# Can you create custom hirelings?

Tags: mods, baldurs-gate-3

Can you create custom hirelings to recruit as companions? Or customize the pre-made ones (beyond class re-specification)?

I don't think it is possible through the vanilla game. Are there any mods which will let me do this?

I think I heard something about Larian Studios releasing example mods for how to create hirelings, but there's no workshop support for BG3 on Steam as of yet, so if such mods exist, I wouldn't know where to find them.

Answer (score 2):

A work around is to start the game multiple times, make a multiplayer game and let them join your party, make the chars and just close the other game instances.

IT is buggy when trying to remove them tho.

Comment: "*IT is buggy when trying to remove them tho.*" Can you elaborate? Removing other players' characters from multiplayer sessions has a built-in process added in Patch #2. What is buggy about it?

Comment: @TylerH didn't know they fixed it yet. USed to be they got stuck in your party, unable to switch out if done this way.

Comment: So no can do if already in a single player campaign?

Comment: @Amarth not that i know,perhaps there is a mod that allows you to change hirelings appearance

Answer (score 2):

Since [Hotfix #9](https://baldursgate3.game/news/hotfix-9-now-live_95) (released October 6th),

> You can now use the Magic Mirror on hirelings.

Same as with Tav, this does currently exclude race or body type, though.

Together with the pre-existing possibility to change the class of hirelings, through Withers, this comes very close (and closest) to being able to create them from scratch.

[image: heh]

Comment: Hehe, "Scratch"